# Improve python csv processing loop

Tags: python, file, csv, optimization

I have a csv file from which I need to export data from a number of columns. Column 4 contains the linename. Whenever the value in this column changes, the data I'm exporting needs to be written to a new, separate file. The following code works, but is rather slow. Any tips on how to improve this?

Addition: sample of the data:

```
Altitude,Date,Db,Depth,Linename,Qmag,TF,TF_HP,X,X_ob,X_org,Y,Y_ob,Y_org
10.87,10/2/2015,148,21.8342,10,1316,48831.936,0.060026123,506479.5515,506479.46,506479.46,5726744.3,5726743.73,5726743.73
10.84,10/2/2015,148,21.8342,11,1316,48831.969,0.092713686,506479.7927,506479.77,506479.77,5726744.443,5726744.2,5726744.2
10.85,10/2/2015,148,21.8669,11,1313,48832.014,0.137400275,506479.9672,506479.77,506479.77,5726744.741,5726744.2,5726744.2
10.82,10/2/2015,148,21.8342,12,1311,48831.969,0.092093953,506480.1677,506479.92,506479.92,5726744.945,5726744.44,5726744.44
10.83,10/2/2015,148,21.8669,12,1309,48831.969,0.091807708,506480.326,506480.08,506480.08,5726745.195,5726744.68,5726744.68
```

Python code:

```
import glob,csv,os, itertools

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/test/*.csv')

directory = 'C:/test/conv/'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
     os.makedirs(directory)

for filename in list_of_files:

    with open(filename,"r") as source:
        header_line = next(source)
        rdr= csv.reader( source, delimiter = ',',lineterminator='\n' )

        x=0

        for row in itertools.islice(rdr,0,None):
            itemRow4 = row[4]
            outfileName=directory+itemRow4+'.csv'

            with open(outfileName,"a") as result:

                wtr=csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')

                if x == 0:
                    previousitemRow4 = row[4]
                    x = x+1                 

                if previousitemRow4 == itemRow4: 
                    wtr.writerow((row[8],row[11],row[6],row[0]))
                    previousitemRow4 = itemRow4
                if previousitemRow4 != itemRow4:
                    wtr.writerow((row[8],row[11],row[6],row[0]))
                    print 'next line'
                    previousitemRow4 = itemRow4
```

Comment: You are opening `outfileName` too often. Append the output lines to a dict of lists and write everything out at the end.

Comment: Not a direct solution/answer to your question, but a more general advise: if you want to check out how much processing time is spent in (each method in) your code, use a profiler. Then, try to optimize where most of the processing time is spent: improve the execution time of the calls, or limit the number of calls to slower parts. See this documentation page on [profiling libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) in Python.

Comment: @eumiro, apparently @Michiel wants a seperate ``outfileName`` for each row. So, he's not opening the same file more than once (unless the ``itemRow4`` contains the same value -- he didn't include an example CSV file with data).

Comment: @Michiel, could you include a (short, but representative) sample of your CSV file in the question?

Comment: @jschulenklopper: I have included a small sample of the file. In the real file, there may be 10,000 lines or more that belong to the same data line (ie, have the same value in row 4)

Comment: The [processing] tag should only be used for the Processing programming language.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: Removed that tag, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Eumiro's suggestion, I have come up with this solution. I tried using a dict of lists but couldn't get it to work. The below solution works and is very fast. Thanks for your help, everyone!

```
import glob,csv,os, itertools

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/test/*.csv')
print 'By the Power of the Python, Split these here files!'  

directory = 'C:/test/conv/'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

for filename in list_of_files:
    storage = []
    specialStorage = []
    with open(filename,"r") as source:
        header_line = next(source)
        rdr= csv.reader( source, delimiter = ',',lineterminator='\n' )
        x=0
        resetValue = 0

        for row in itertools.islice(rdr,0,None):
            itemRow4 = row[4]

            if x == 0:
                previousitemRow4 = row[4]
                x = x+1

            outfileName=directory+previousitemRow4+'.csv'        

            if previousitemRow4 == itemRow4:                 

                storage.append((row[8],row[11],row[6],row[0]))
                previousitemRow4 = itemRow4

            if previousitemRow4 != itemRow4:

                with open(outfileName,"a") as result:

                    wtr=csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
                    previousitemRow4 = itemRow4

                    if len(specialStorage) !=0:
                        wtr.writerow(specialStorage)
                    wtr.writerows(storage)
                    storage = []

                specialStorage=(row[8],row[11],row[6],row[0])

        else:
            with open(outfileName,"a") as result:

                    wtr=csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
                    previousitemRow4 = itemRow4
                    wtr.writerow(specialStorage)
                    wtr.writerows(storage)
                    storage = []

            print 'end of file reached'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard Unix shell tools [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq), and [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
$ cut -d, -f5 < in.csv | sort | uniq | while read lineno
do
  grep ",${lineno}," in.csv > out-${lineno}.csv
done
$ ls out-*.csv
out-10.csv  out-11.csv  out-12.csv out-Linename.csv
```

Maybe the `grep` expression is not sophisticated enough because the lineno  may appear in other columns but the 5th. In this case, a simple regular expression can be used to make `grep` findthe lineno only in the 5th column.

Comment: Impressive, thanks. I'm on a windows machine though, and only have python at my disposal.